# How can I parameterize a generic method so as not to repeat the structure of the tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have a Spring Boot project in which I am adding the below `Test` of some of the classes.

```
    @Test
    void documentException() {
        assertThrows(DocumentException.class, () -> {
            try {
                throw new DocumentException();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                assertEquals("Error converting document format", ex.getMessage());
                assertEquals(417 /* EXPECTATION_FAILED */, ex.getHttpStatus());
                assertEquals(ErrorCodes.DOCUMENT_ERROR, ex.getCode());
                throw ex;
            }
        });
    }

@Test
    void maxUserException() {
        assertThrows(MaxUserException.class, () -> {
            try {
                Integer maxUsers = 5;
                throw new MaxUserException(maxUsers);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Integer maxUsers = 5;
                assertEquals("Excedido el nÃºmero mÃ¡ximo de "+ maxUsers +" dispositivos", ex.getMessage());
                assertEquals(403 /* FORBIDDEN */, ex.getHttpStatus());
                assertEquals(ErrorCodes.MAX_USERS_DEVICES, ex.getCode());
                throw ex;
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Test
    void docFormatException() {
        assertThrows(DocFormatException.class, () -> {
            try {
                throw new DocFormatException();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                assertEquals("Document format", ex.getMessage());
                assertEquals(415 /* UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE */, ex.getHttpStatus());
                assertEquals(ErrorCodes.DOCUMENT_ERROR, ex.getCode());
                throw ex;
            }
        });
    }
```

For each class I use the same `method`.

Would there be any way to create a class with a `@Test` and call it for each class? So as not to have to create such a large structure for each of the classes.

What I want is to make a general method and apply it to each of the classes. So as not to have to repeat the same structure for all classes.

Comment: How about having a common util containing the same method and reused in all the tests? These looks like API level UTs, and you might be having multiple APIs throwing the same document conversion exception.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, As per my understanding you are trying to create a method which needs to be called from different classes ?. If my understanding is correct try to refractor the code, If you have redundant code refractor it to use common method and utilise in other place which will help you to write effective test cases.

Comment: Create a base test class and put common functions in that. Then extend that base class in all your test classes. Use `@Before` and `@BeforeEach` as per your requirements.

Comment: what exactly are you testing using this test?

Comment: What I am able to test are small exceptions for each class, after doing many tests I am looking for a way to make a unique parameterized method so as not to repeat the entire structure every time, but I don't know how to do it. I have created a separate class only with a Test (the one in the question), but I don't know how to call it for each class or how I have to continue to parameterize it.

Comment: the test design is a bit questionable, I mean assertThrows are used if something throws certain exception, but you thrown it by yourself. Why do you need assertThrows is the first place?

Comment: To affirm ambien in the message the type of data, they work better this way. But how can I parameterize this method? I have the method created in a separate class but I don't know how to follow.

Comment: well, it's still not really clear what you want to achieve, could you post another tests examples?

Comment: What I want is to make a common ``Test`` method to apply to each class, instead of creating this method for each class

Comment: It will be better to mention in the question, how you are structuring say 2-3 classes which can leverage common test as per your question. My understanding is either you can have a single class having common exception handler logic in source and have an UT for that or have a common test util with the asserts can be reused across UTs. I somehow feel this as a [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: You can create a class something like TestUtils, create a static method there where you pass your exception, message, http code, and error code and throw exception there and do assertions. Then you can call it from your test methods, if you really need it. You still would need a separate test methods, but you wouldn't need to repeat the same code over and over again.  But again, I would reconsider tests design, maybe you wouldn't need those tests at all.

Comment: Ok if that's what you had in mind, create a separate class with a test method. But I don't know how to target from another class. Could you give an example? because I can't do it

Answer (score 0):

Well, answering *directly* to your question and using your actual examples - if you want to avoid code duplication then you can use some utility method.

Assuming your exceptions are subtypes of your custom class or implement the same interface which have methods `getHttpStatus` and `getCode`. Let's say parent class or interface has name `CustomException`.

Create a new class, for example `TestUtils` and define the method which can be reused is your tests, something like that (idk what type `getCode()` should return, so I assume it's `String`)

```
public class TestUtils {

    public static void testException(CustomException exception, String message, 
        String errorCode, int httpStatus) {
    
        assertThrows(exception.getClass(), () -> {
            try {
                throw exception;
            } catch (CustomException ex) {
                assertEquals(message, ex.getMessage());
                assertEquals(httpStatus, ex.getHttpStatus());
                assertEquals(errorCode, ex.getCode());
                throw ex;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then your test methods can be simplified:

```
    @Test
    void documentException() {
       TestUtils.testException(new DocumentException(), 
           "Error converting document format",
           417,
           ErrorCodes.DOCUMENT_ERROR);           
    }
```

maxUserException() a bit trickier but still works:

```
@Test
void maxUserException() {
    int maxUsers = 5;
    MaxUserException exception = new MaxUserException(maxUsers);
    String message = "Excedido el nÃºmero mÃ¡ximo de "+ maxUsers +" dispositivos";
    TestUtils.testException(exception, message, ErrorCodes.MAX_USERS_DEVICES, 403);
}
```

Hope it can be helpful. However it's worth mentioning - if it's your real test code and it's written exactly like this, then those methods attempt to test that your custom exceptions are created with correct default parameters (that's all) and in that case, test methods can be simplified as they are overcomplicated right now.

Comment: All the tests I have in a class ``ExceptionTest.java``, but I don't have a main class as you say, they are all independent classes. How can I do that without having a main class? I don't have a class like ``CustomException`` common to all.

Comment: I thought your exceptions do have common parent since they have same methods like  `ex.getHttpStatus()` and `ex.getCode()`. If they don't then it's worth to create an interface or a parent class for you custom exceptions. Your examples won't compile if your `ex` variable in your catch clause  `} catch (Exception ex) {` is `java.lang.Exception` type, because `java.lang.Exception`  does not have methods like `ex.getHttpStatus()` and `ex.getCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example test methods seems bit complicated, but it worth mentioning there in `JUnit5` there are annotations to handle parameterized test.
You should look into these documents:

Java doc for [@ParameterizedTest](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParameterizedTest.html) ,  [@ValueSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/ValueSource.html) , [@CsvSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/CsvSource.html).

here is a sample example of how to parameterized a test:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource(value = {
                      // input and expected output separated by :
                     "test:test",
                     "tEst:test",
                     "Java:java"
                   }, delimiter = ':')
void toLowerCase_ShouldGenerateTheExpectedLowercaseValue(String input, String expected) {
    String actualValue = input.toLowerCase();
    assertEquals(expected, actualValue);
}
```

Have a look in this [Guide to JUnit 5 Parameterized Tests](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5).